# i have issue with design the ListTile in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i an trying to design the add to cart button when user click on 'add to cart' the 'add to cart' button hides and ListTile appear that is on back of button and listtile have three things title , leading and trailing everything is works like i want but issue is i want the same size of list tile as button size so it won't grow when listtile appear on screen

here is the video to clear what i mean

https://youtu.be/Bq2mrc5ao94

here is my code

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int total=0;
  bool cartbuttoncheck=true;
  bool listbool=false;
  IconData delete_icon=Icons.remove;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Button"),

        ),
        body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Visibility(
                      visible: listbool,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: 50.0,
                          width: 160.0,
                          child: ListTile(

                            title: Center(child: Text(total.toString(),style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,color: Colors.white),)),
                            leading: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(delete_icon,color: Colors.white,),
                              onPressed: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  if(total==2)
                                    {
                                      print("i am 2");
                                      delete_icon=Icons.delete;
                                      total--;
                                    }
                                 else if(total==1 && delete_icon==Icons.delete)
                                  {
                                    total=0;
                                    listbool=false;
                                    cartbuttoncheck=true;
                                  }
                               if(total>2)
                                    {
                                   //   delete_icon=Icons.remove;
                                      total--;
                                    }
                                });

                              },
                            ),
                            trailing: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white),

                              onPressed: (){
                                setState(() {
                                  if(total==1 && delete_icon==Icons.delete)
                                    {
                                      delete_icon=Icons.remove;
                                    }
                                  total++;

                                });

                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[

                        Visibility(
                          visible: cartbuttoncheck,
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              setState(() {
                                cartbuttoncheck=false;
                                listbool=true;
                                if(total==0)
                                  {
                                    total++;
                                    delete_icon=Icons.delete;
                                  }
                              });
                            },
              child: Text("Add to Cart",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like the ListTile uses a SizedBox with a defined size you can do the same to the RaisedButton

```
SizedBox(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 160.0,
  child: RaisedButton(
    onPressed: (){
      setState(() {
        cartbuttoncheck=false;
        listbool=true;
        if(total==0){
          total++;
          delete_icon=Icons.delete;
        }
       });
    },
    child: Text("Add to Cart",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
    color: Colors.green,
  ),
)
```

Having said that I believe it would be better to not use all of the widgets you use(Column, Stack, Visibility) and just change between the ListTile and the RaisedButton based on a bool value (listbool for example)

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int total = 0;
  bool listbool = false;
  IconData delete_icon = Icons.remove;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Button"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            height: 50.0,
            width: 160.0,
            child: listbool
                ? ListTile(
                    title: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      total.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        delete_icon,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (total == 2) {
                            print("i am 2");
                            delete_icon = Icons.delete;
                            total--;
                          } else if (total == 1 &&
                              delete_icon == Icons.delete) {
                            total = 0;
                            listbool = false;
                          }
                          if (total > 2) {
                            //   delete_icon=Icons.remove;
                            total--;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (total == 1 && delete_icon == Icons.delete) {
                            delete_icon = Icons.remove;
                          }
                          total++;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        listbool = true;
                        if (total == 0) {
                          total++;
                          delete_icon = Icons.delete;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Add to Cart",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you have a container of a specific size of color green in the center and based on the value of the listbool it changes its child to the ListTile and RaisedButton

**UPDATE**

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  double width; //the width of the RaisedButton based on the text
  double height; //the heightof the RaisedButton based on the text
  EdgeInsets myPadding = EdgeInsets.all(8); //a known padding to use in the RaisedButton
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    TextSpan longestParagraphTest = TextSpan(
      text: "Add to Cart",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
    );
    TextPainter _textPainter = TextPainter(text: longestParagraphTest, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, maxLines: 1)..layout(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
    width = _textPainter.width + 16; //this is the padding
    height = _textPainter.height + 16; //this is the padding
  }
  
  int total = 0;
  bool listbool = false;
  IconData delete_icon = Icons.remove;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Button"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            color: Colors.green,
            height: height,
            width: width, //now you know the size of the RaisedButton and use it in both the ListTile and RaisedButton
            child: listbool
                ? ListTile(
                    title: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      total.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, color: Colors.white),
                    )),
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        delete_icon,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (total == 2) {
                            print("i am 2");
                            delete_icon = Icons.delete;
                            total--;
                          } else if (total == 1 &&
                              delete_icon == Icons.delete) {
                            total = 0;
                            listbool = false;
                          }
                          if (total > 2) {
                            //   delete_icon=Icons.remove;
                            total--;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (total == 1 && delete_icon == Icons.delete) {
                            delete_icon = Icons.remove;
                          }
                          total++;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                : RaisedButton(
                  padding: myPadding,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        listbool = true;
                        if (total == 0) {
                          total++;
                          delete_icon = Icons.delete;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Add to Cart",
                      maxLines: 1,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And you will get something like this because the button size is too small for a ListTile to show 2 icons and a text

[image]
[image]

I have 2 recommendations if you want to keep it this way, in the initState change the minWidth in `layout(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: double.infinity);` to a greater value (let's say 100.0) just to be sure in case your minWidth is too small it changes to 100 to fit the ListTile. My second recommendation is to use an AnimatedContainer and change the size based on the widget displayed

```
AnimatedContainer(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  color: Colors.green,
  height: listbool ? 50.0 : height, //it animates to a a better size to fit the listTile
  width: listbool ? 200.0 : width, //it animates to a a better size to fit the listTile
  child: listbool ? ListTile(...) : RaisedButton(...),
),
```

where height and width are the values calculated in the initState. It will do a smooth animation between the 2 sizes (just like your video but smoother and cleaner)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want the list tile with the size of raisedbutoon don't want to change the size of button want to resize the listtile

Comment: The problem you could face with that is that the RaisedButton size depends of its child, in htis case the Text Widget, and you don't know that yet, there is a way to calculate that, but even if you do if the width is too small for the listtile to display you will get an error

Comment: so what is the suggested solution

Comment: check the update, basically made a TextSpan in the initState just to calculate what would be the size of the text and use it in the size of the container, but maybe an AnimatedContainer can give you a better look without making your app stutter or weird while changing size